# Passing MS Teams context to an office addin

Tags: office-js, microsoft-teams

When Office 365 is invoked in Microsoft Teams how does one percolate the teams context to the office Host or rather the office add-in environment? Is there any support in the Teams SDK or Office API for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access the Microsoft Teams context when running inside Microsoft Teams.

Comment: I am editing the word document inside MS Teams and my add-in also runs in the Office host running within MS Teams. I have written the following JS script

Comment: I have written JS script in my office add-in to initialize the microsoftteams environment and to read the context but they dont return anything. Are you saying that such a scenario of Office running within MSTeams is not supported in the Teams SDK